# Landscape mode breaks layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, landscape-portrait

My app looks perfect in Portrait mood in almost all devices. But in Landscape mode it breaks and places Views on top on one another. I have GenyMotion plugin with Android Studio and I have tried by installing  different types of devices, however, the problems remains same.

Here is an example of Portrait mode:

[image: Portrait]

Landscape mode:

[image: Landscape]

.XML file:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerValue"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textColor="#cd0000"
        android:text="@string/timerVal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="@string/startButtonLabel"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#fffaf0"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="196dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="39dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
        android:text="@string/pauseButtonLabel"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#fffaf0"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextClock
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/textClock"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="RESET"
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#000080"
        android:textColor="#DC143C"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/fbshare"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Because that's the layout you specified. Setting a 30dp margin above something means there will always be 30dp above it. Consider creating a landscape-specific layout and placing it in the `layout-land` directory, which is used when the device is in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another directory inside res, and name it `layout-land`, it's similar to what you have to do with multilanguage values directory.

It means that there are two different activitis for anything: the portrait one in the layout folder, and the landscape one that is in the layout-land folder, and both have the same name.

Once you have created the landscape activity you can edit it as you want

Comment: Well you don't have to but it certainly does allow you more freedom

Comment: thank you for you answer! But, I got incomplete idea. Can you be alittle bit more specific? Are you sure that I have to make a directory inside res or you meant a XML resource file? Ok after I make a directory do I need to create a XML file inside that directory? If I do so then would it affect my portrait mood?

Comment: You can make a directory and then copy all the activities that you want to have a different layout for the landscape mode, into this directory keeping the same name. Then you can make all the changes to this activities in the layout-land directory. Android Studio also shows you the phone in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

This should get the job mostly done. As others have said it's generally best to create layouts specifically for landscape.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textColor="#cd0000"
        android:text="00:00:00"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="Start"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#fffaf0"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fbutton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fbutton"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="Pause"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#fffaf0"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fbutton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fbutton"/>

    <TextClock
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textClock"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RESET"
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#000080"
        android:textColor="#DC143C"
        android:layout_above="@id/fbutton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fbutton"
        android:src="@drawable/fbshare"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```